# Python+Altair (Vega-Lite): Web server

Tags: python, web, altair

I want to visualize some graphs on web pages using Python 2.7.12 and Altair 1.2.0.

Using their examples it is easy and straightforward:

```
from altair import *
from altair import Chart, load_dataset

# load built-in dataset as a pandas DataFrame
cars = load_dataset('cars')

chart = Chart(cars).mark_circle().encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
)

chart.display()
```

This works in Jupyter Notebook.

Changing `chart.display()` to `chart.server()` (as described at https://altair-viz.github.io/documentation/displaying.html#displaying-plots-via-a-local-http-server) should be enough to start a web server using Python's HTTPServer.

It starts, but the page it provides is empty. The source is there but nothing is visualized.

Any idea about why?

Comment: I have the same problem. When I do `savechart` (should generate HTML as in `chart.serve()`), it gives the correct HTML file. However, I cannot display it on browser.

Comment: I was able to replicate this issue. Please see: https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/315

Comment: `chart.serve()` is working as expected for me (altair 2.1.0). The documentation has moved to here https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/display_frontends.html?e#working-in-non-notebook-environments

Answer (score 0):

Adding my previous comment as an answer:

chart.serve() is working as expected for me (altair 2.1.0). The documentation has moved to here https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/display_frontends.html?e#working-in-non-notebook-environments

```py
from altair import Chart, load_dataset

# load built-in dataset as a pandas DataFrame
cars = load_dataset('cars')

chart = Chart(cars).mark_circle().encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
)

chart.serve()
```